# what is the difference between ∀x∈ℝ, ∀ε>0, (|x|≤ε ⇒ x=0) and ∀x∈ℝ, ((∀ε>0, |x|≤ε) ⇒ x=0)

Tags: proof-writing, quantifiers

I am supposed to Prove or disprove: ∀x∈ℝ, ∀ε>0, (|x|≤ε ⇒ x=0)
and: ∀x∈ℝ, ((∀ε>0,|x|≤ε) ⇒ x=0)

I think I understand how to prove the second one (by contradiction) but I don't understand what makes it different from the first one.

Comment: Hint: in the second one you can't exchange the quantifiers because one of them is inside an implication statement. But in the first one you can exchange the quantifiers, since they are adjacent.

Answer (score 1):

The statement says that, if we take any real number $x$ and any $\varepsilon > 0$ with $|x| \leq \varepsilon$, then we have $x = 0$. But it is far from being true; just too many counterexamples are available; take $x := 1$ and $\varepsilon := 2$, for example.

However, the second statement says that, if we take any real number whose absolute value is less than or equal to every given number $> 0$, then we have the fact that the real number is $=0$.

Answer (score 1):

The first sentence,
$$
(\forall x\in \Bbb R)(\forall \varepsilon > 0)\,(\lvert x\rvert\le \varepsilon \Rightarrow x=0)
$$
is equivalent to
$$
(\forall x\in \Bbb R)\,((\exists \varepsilon > 0)\,(\lvert x\rvert\le \varepsilon) \Rightarrow x=0)
$$
because

- $\varepsilon$ doesn't occur in the conclusion of the implication,
- $p\Rightarrow q$ is equivalent to $\neg p\lor q$,
- $(\forall v)\,(r\lor s)$ is equivalent to $(\forall v)\,r\lor s$ if $v$ doesn't occur in $q$,
- $\forall v\,\neg\,p$ is equivalent to $\neg\,\exists v\,p$.

So the sentence says: if there is some $\varepsilon > 0$ such that $\lvert x\rvert \le \varepsilon$, then $x=0$. This is clearly false.

The second sentence, however, is true.

Answer (score 0):

The second is a statement about all real numbers $x$. Namely that if $|x|$ is smaller than all $\varepsilon > 0$, then $x$ is 0.

The first is a statement about all *pairs* of numbers $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\varepsilon > 0$. Namely that whenever the $|x| \le \varepsilon$, we can conclude that $x = 0$. But we can find many pairs $x$ and $\varepsilon > 0$ where $x \neq 0$ where we have $|x| \le \varepsilon$. So this disproves the simple implication.

In the second the $\forall \epsilon>0$ statement is as a whole the assumption of the implication which is much stronger.